# How do you avoid running hyperlinks that include the page's footer and header?

Tags: hyperref, header-footer, page-breaking, urls

Please consider this MWE:

```
\documentclass[paper=a6,fontsize=11pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\chapter{My Chapter}
\lipsum[2] \url{https://example.com/}
\end{document}
```

Using `pdflatex`, this results in:

[image: The running hyperlink includes the current page footer and next page header]

Where the boxes for the current page footer and next page header are part of the running link.

This is similar to [Why is there an extra link box for long URLs when using hyperref and lineno?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/609170/190398), and since I'm using `pdflatex`, it looks like I should use `\pdfrunninglinkoff` before the footer box and `\pdfrunninglinkon` after the header box, but how can I find the correct boxes to patch?

Comment: in a current LaTeX you can use `\DocumentMetadata{testphase=new-or-1}` see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/578405/2388 (it doesn't catch everything, if you have footnotes that split over pages you can still get such links.)

Comment: I would also try very hard not to break urls over pages, if only to make them more readable.  This will not be easy since you still need line breaks.

Comment: BTW: The problem is independent from KOMA-Script. It happens, e.g., also with `\documentclass[a5paper]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\chapter{My Chapter}
\lipsum[11]\par
\lipsum[11]
\url{https://example.com/somewhere/here/or/there}
\end{document}`

Comment: Thank you. `\DocumentMetadata{testphase=new-or-1}` worked in my document. The old `xpatch` solution from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/578405/2388 worked too.